# Copying and Pasting Range of Data to specific date cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code which works and is awesome however it can only find the current date we are in (because of DateValue (now)) I would like this to be set off a cell value instead on the "Input" Worksheet (Cell D4) in particular.

Anyone know how?

```
Sub FindToday()

Dim FoundDate As Range
Set FoundDate = Worksheets("Data").Columns("A").Find(DateValue(Now), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not FoundDate Is Nothing Then ' if we don't find the date, simply skip.
    Worksheets("Input").Range("A4:H4").Copy
    FoundDate.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False ' You can see that the first argument in PasteSpecial is set to only paste values.
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a range instead:

```
Sub FindToday()
Dim searchDate as Range

Dim FoundDate As Range
Set searchDate = Worksheets("Input").Range("D4")
Set FoundDate = Worksheets("Data").Columns("A").Find(searchDate.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not FoundDate Is Nothing Then ' if we don't find the date, simply skip.
    Worksheets("Input").Range("A4:H4").Copy
    FoundDate.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False ' You can see that the first argument in PasteSpecial is set to only paste values.
End If
End Sub
```

Or maybe you would do `...Find(DateValue(searchDate.value)...`

Answer (score 0):

here's one that pops up an input box so you can choose to alter the target date from now a number of days: like, enter -3 and it puts the data in for 3 days ago... is something like *this* what you were looking for? Or did you want it to copy *all* new data? or just all data regardless of date?

```
Sub FindToday()
Dim N As Long
Dim FoundDate As Range
N = Application.InputBox("Enter Date Offset:", "Date Selector")
If N = False Then Exit Sub
Set FoundDate = Worksheets("Data").Columns("A").Find(DateValue(Now + N), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not FoundDate Is Nothing Then ' if we don't find the date, simply skip.
    Worksheets("Input").Range("A4:H4").Copy
    FoundDate.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False ' You can see that the first argument in PasteSpecial is set to only paste values.
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I had a hard time figuring what you meant by: "I would like this to be set off _a cell value_ instead on the "Input" Worksheet (Cell D4) in particular." But is sounds like you wanted to pick a date other than 'Now'

Comment: Ho Reverus apologies for not making sense but yes that's what I would like to pick a date other than now

Comment: cool, well... the method above is *one* way lol, depending on the user however, it would perhaps be more ideal to specify a date in a date format... instead of +3 or -12... which is most likely more cumbersome that it needs to be ;) lemme know, I do this for fun so I'd be willing to work it towards a more "user-friendly" format

Comment: Cheers for the help Reverus I found the guy below with the range worked absolutely spot on dude I appreciate your time though!